# Access Derby DB created by another application

Tags: java, derby

I use a licensed software for data processing, Nuix. It creates an embedded Derby Database to store info about the data it processes.

My question is: is it possible for me to access the database the program creates even if I do not run the program? I want to access the database from my own JVM application.

Please note: I have never used Derby before nor am I fluent in Java.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, although the application may have placed authentication or encryption on the database which will require you to know the right credentials and passwords.

Comment: @BryanPendleton thanks. I would still try it out. Good day to you.

Comment: Great! Start by installing a tool like SquirrelSQL and configure the Derby support in that tool; it's much easier to explore an unfamiliar database instance with a visual database browsing tool.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have used RazorSQL to browse Nuix DBs. Point it to a store folder and it should display the tables. Not the easiest Schema to understand but you should be able to find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Derby, like all databases, ultimately stores it's data on your HDD or SSD. And like many others, it stores them I files. So any other program with access to the files can access the data, in theory. You could shutdown the other program and have your own program or a Derby server daemon  access the files, using the same Derby Java library version.

But you will face one problem: you will not know the database schema. So it might be difficult to interpret the data you read.